# Create an expression dynamically to sort Linq to Entities ascending/descending based on a dynamically provided property name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Here is what I am trying to do. I have done a few simple expressions, but this one is a little too much for me right now.

```
    public static Expression<Func<IQueryable<TEntityType>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntityType>>> SortMeDynamically<TEntityType>(bool isAsc, string propertyname)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntityType), "x");
        var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyname);
        var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);

        string sortOrder = isAsc ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

        var selector = Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        sortOrder,
        new[] { prop.Type},
        sortLambda);

        var lambda = Lambda<Func<IQueryable<TEntityType>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntityType>>>(selector, param);
        return lambda;
    }
```

The error I get is the following.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic
```

The closest solution I found was the one below.

[LINQ to Entities OrderBy Expression Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755441/linq-to-entities-orderby-expression-tree)

Comment: That order by method has 2 generic parameters `new Type[] { typeof(TEntityType), prop.Type }` and two parameters, the source query and the sort lambda, and finally returning an `IOrderedQueryable<TEntityType>` .

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do half of the linked answer. You can either return your `Expression<Func<>> sortLambda` so the caller can call `.OrderBy / .OrderByDescending` with their query. Or, like the linked answer, you can emulate how the `.OrderBy / etc` call works.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks again. I just needed some help, this definitely helps. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the various `.OrderBy` linq methods dynamically is quite a pain.

The most difficult part of this process is locating the `MethodInfo` of the four relevant `Queryable.OrderBy` methods, with the correct generic constraints. There are a number of ways to achieve this.

You could pull the method out of a template `Expression<Func<...>>`, as in your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34755931/4139809);

```cs
Expression<Func<IOrderedEnumerable<TEntityType>>> sortMethod = 
    (() => query.OrderBy<TEntityType, object>(k => null));

var methodCallExpression = (sortMethod.Body as MethodCallExpression);
var method = methodCallExpression.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

You could use `Type.GetMethods` and filter the results. Though you'd have to worry about future runtime changes breaking this approach.

```cs
var method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod
        && m.Name == nameof(Queryable.OrderBy)
        && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .Single();
```

In both cases you'd then need to call `.MakeGenericMethod` to supply the correct generic parameters.

```cs
var genericSortMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntityType), prop.Type);
```

Or you could create a delegate and pull the method from there. Again, getting the generic constraints correct is a bit fiddly. But can be easier with a helper method. Which is similar to how the linq runtime locates this `MethodInfo`.

```cs
public MethodInfo GetOrderFunc<T, V>(Func<IQueryable<T>, Expression<Func<T, V>>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> func)
    => func.Method;

var genericSortMethod = GetOrderFunc<TEntityType, V>(Queryable.OrderBy);
```

If you don't know the argument value type, you could call that method via reflection.

Now you can either invoke the method;

```cs
var orderedQuery = (IOrderedQueryable<TEntityType>)genericSortMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, sortLambda });
```

Or by reading the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b4c76da8e8bddce2ffdf0d96574188b9ec20d151/src/libraries/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/Queryable.cs#L153), recreate what those methods actually do.

```cs
var expression = query.Expression;

expression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable), 
    genericSortMethod,
    new Type[] { typeof(TEntityType), prop.Type },
    expression, 
    Expression.Quote(sortLambda));

var orderedQuery = (IOrderedQueryable<T>)query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
```

No matter how you approach this, you need to take an `IQueryable<TEntity> query` parameter, and return an `IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>`. Or just stop at creating the `Expression<Func<>>`.

The other, other option is to move all the generic mucking around into a helper method. Then invoke that method via reflection. Obtaining the generic `MethodInfo` using one of the same approaches explained above.

```cs
public IOrderedQueryable<T> Order<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, V>> key, bool then, bool desc)
    => (desc)
        ? (then ? ((IOrderedQueryable<T>)query).ThenByDescending(key) : query.OrderByDescending(key))
        : (then ? ((IOrderedQueryable<T>)query).ThenBy(key) : query.OrderBy(key));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details. I will give it a try as you have explained.